# Camel Spring Java Config Camel 2.15 vs Camel 2.17

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have a sample project setup on camel 2.17 where I setup a Camel Spring Java config main and everything was happy.  When I tried adjusting my version to camel 2.15 I noticed that the .setConfigClass(Object.class) method was not valid.  Is there a different way of configuring this on Camel 2.15?

```
import org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.CamelConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.Main;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mcf.xml.free.route")
public class RouteJavaConfig extends CamelConfiguration {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        //This method here doesn't exist for Camel 2.15 but does for 2.17
        main.setConfigClass(RouteJavaConfig.class);
        main.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes newer Apache Camel versions improves and adds new features and whatnot.

That method is not available in Camel 2.15, and you need to upgrade if you want to use it.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish the same thing in camel 2.15?  I am currently leveraging FUSE 6.2 at my company so upgrading to 2.17 won't happen until FUSE releases a newer version

Comment: You can use the Red Hat customer portal to log a ticket to have this method added in a patch for Fuse 6.2.